# How to add active class on a nested route in React js dashboard?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I use a nested route to make a dashboard. When I try to set active class on the dashboard sidebar, the previous navlink active class is not removed when I got to next link. They have a common route Dashboard [image: Here The screenshot]

```
const Sidebar = () => {
  return (
    <div className=' bg-white min-h-screen px-12'>
      <ul>
        {SidebarData?.map(singleData =>
          <li className='py-5' key={singleData?.id}>
            <span className='flex items-center'>
              <img
                className='mr-[.8rem] w-[25px] h-[28px]'
                src={singleData?.icon} alt=""
              />
              <NavLink
                className={({ isActive }) =>
                  isActive ? 'bg-green-500 font-bold' : 'bg-red-500 font-thin'
                }
                to={singleData?.link}
              >
                {singleData?.name}
              </NavLink>
            </span>
          </li>
        )}
      </ul>
    </div >
  );
};

export default Sidebar;
```